# Defining a radical of a module axiomatically

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

In [these](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~rvale/fdalgebras.pdf#page=9) notes by Richard Vale, he approaches the notion of a radical of a module axiomatically, by saying the following. A *radical* is an assignment, to each R-module $M$, of a submodule $\tau(M) \triangleleft M$, such that

1. $f(\tau(M)) \subset \tau(N)$ for all $f: M \to N$.
2. For all $M$, $\tau(M/\tau(M)) = 0$.

He then goes on to prove some nice properties one can derive from these assumptions.

My question is: in the particular case of the Jacobson radical, I thought $f(J(R)) \subseteq J(S)$ was not true in general, and only becomes true when $f$ is a surjective ring map. So what gives?

Comment: If $R$ is a local domain with fraction field $K$ and maximal ideal $J$ (it is also the Jacobson radical), then clearly the inclusion $i: R \to K$ does not map $J$ to $0$. Hence, the Jacobson radical does not satisfy these axioms.

Comment: But the definition you quoted is for radicals **of modules**, not of rings. So «what gives» is nothing :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Huh. I would have thought the radical of a ring would be its radical as a module over itself. Why would this not be? The author indicates that this is the approach followed it the text by Beachy. I haven't been able to get a hold of that book yet.

Comment: @EricAuld The ring version typically is the module version, yes, but that doesn't let you interchange ring homomorphisms with module homomorphisms. Have you seen that the statement holds with the Jacobson radical and *module* homomorphisms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:R\to S$ is a morphism of rings, and you view it as a morphism if R-modules, then it is true that it maps the radical of R into the radical of S, but of S viewed as an R-module.

The thing is, the radical of S as an R-module is not the same thing as the radical of S as an S-module.